# Push data on array when checkbox is checked and remove data when checkbox is unchecked

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am taking data from table and display as multi check checkboxes.My checkboxes when checked pushes data  on array for that particular checkbox.But when unchecked ,the respective data should be  removed from the array.How can I achieve this?

HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="data in filters.status" >
    <label class="Form-label--tick">
        <input type="checkbox" value="data.id" id="status" ng-model="status" class="Form-label-checkbox"  ng-change="IfCheck(data.id,status)" >
        <span class="Form-label-text"> {{data.status}}</span>
    </label>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
<script>
    $scope.IfCheck = function (data, check) {
        if (check) {
            status.push(data);
            $scope.checkedData[0].status = status;
        }
        else {
            var index = $scope.status.indexOf(data);
            $scope.status.splice(index);
        }

    };
</script>
```

Comment: upload your code on plunker

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can be written as like this:

```js
var app = angular.module('sa', []);
app.controller('FooCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.ids = [];

  $scope.filters = [{
    id: 1,
    status: false
  }, {
    id: 2,
    status: false
  }, {
    id: 3,
    status: false
  }]

  $scope.IfCheck = function(id, check) {
    if (check) {
      $scope.ids.push(id);
    } else {
      var index = $scope.ids.indexOf(id);
      $scope.ids.splice(index, 1);
    }
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="sa" ng-controller="FooCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="data in filters">
    <label class="Form-label--tick">
      <input type="checkbox" value="data.id" id="status" ng-model="data.status" class="Form-label-checkbox" ng-change="IfCheck(data.id, data.status)">
      <span class="Form-label-text"> {{data.status}}</span>
    </label>
  </div>

  Selected ids: {{ids}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can utilize the `ng-model` to see if the input is checked or unchecked. Note that I simplified the code, so you will need to add in your various attributes and logic to what's below:

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="isChecked" ng-change="IfCheck()">
```

JS:

```
$scope.isChecked = false;

$scope.IfCheck = function () {
  if ($scope.isChecked === true) {
    // checked
  } else {
    // unchecked
  }
};
```

This is the [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/N5HBoZUMFKW54xtVrA3g) plnkr for a checkbox input with `ng-model` that is on the Angular [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bcheckbox%5D).

**For multiple checkboxes, you will need to track something like `isChecked` for each checkbox.**